# Query from AWS DynamoDB for Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to fetch data from my AWS DynamoDB database.  I have the following code set up, however I am getting errors.  Unclear how to proceed from here in order to query the data based on primary key

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.*;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
        getApplicationContext(),
        "**********************", // Identity Pool ID
        Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
);

AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddbClient);
```

Comment: Can you connect to Dynamo db Independently from other tool ?

Comment: yes, i have separate code for the creation of the database and insertion of data.  i am now trying to use the android application to pull this data from the database once it is stored

Comment: "however I am getting errors" is not enough information! How do you expect anyone to be able to help you without knowing what the exact error is? Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then update your question to include the necessary information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First comment, it looks like you are trying to this in an Activity -- this will definitely throw Network on Main Thread exception in Android.

Second, as a general guide, you need to set up a separate class with your DynamoDB fields set up and linked to variables in the class.  For example:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = SA_AWSConstants.QUESTIONTABLENAME)
public class SA_Question implements Comparable<SA_Question> {

    // fields coming from AWS table
    private String questionguid_str; // : STRING, PRIMARY HASH KEY
    private String json_str;
    private long ordinalposition_int;

    ...

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = SA_AWSConstants.DBSCHEMA_QUESTIONGUID)
    public String getQuestionguid_str() {
        return questionguid_str;
    }

    public void setQuestionguid_str(String questionguid_str) {
        this.questionguid_str = questionguid_str;
    }

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = SA_AWSConstants.DBSCHEMA_ORDINALPOS)
    public long getOrdinalposition_int() {
        return ordinalposition_int;
    }

    public void setOrdinalposition_int(long ordinalposition_int) {
        this.ordinalposition_int = ordinalposition_int;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = SA_AWSConstants.DBSCHEMA_QUESTION_JSONSTR)
    public String getJson_str() {
        return json_str;
    }

    public void setJson_str(String json_str) {
        this.json_str = json_str;
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
                DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddb);
                DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();

                PaginatedScanList<SA_Question> paginatedq = mapper.scan(SA_Question.class, scanExpression);
                ArrayList<SA_Question> awsqlist = new ArrayList<SA_Question>();

                for (SA_Question q : paginatedq) {
                    q.initiateFromJSON();
                    awsqlist.add(q);
                }
```

You have to be mindful of the limits AWS sets on returns of data with a single query (hence the PaginatedScan -- if you expect to exceed the limit then you will need to check whether more data exists to be returned).

Comment: thanks for the help, i was getting the Network on Main Thread exception.  what is the SA_AWSConstants that you are using? i am also getting "cannot resolve method 'initiateFromJSON()", also how would you code SA_Question q : paginatedq without the enhanced for loop. thanks

Comment: The code I posted was an example from a personal project -- initiatefromJSON() was a function of SA_Question I didn't include in the post for clarity purposes.  You won't be able to copy the SA_Question class or the for... loop directly, you will need to modify it for your specific table.